# How can I get the list of targets in an export set?

Tags: cmake

I'm installing targets with a command like this:

```
install(TARGETS my_target EXPORT my_export_set ...)
```

Once I've added a number of targets to an export set, over multiple `install` commands, how can I get the list of targets included in the export set? I'm looking for something like this:

```
get_property(targets INSTALL my_export_set PROPERTY TARGETS)
```